# How to maintain List of mutable objects inside immutable class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, immutability, mutable

I have Immutable class and which has list of Mutable class objects.

```
class Immutable
{
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final List<Mutable> list;
    Immutable(int id,String name,List<Mutable> list)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.list=list;
    }
    
    public List<Mutable> getMutables()
    {
        List<Mutable> l=new ArrayList<>(this.list);
        return l;
    }
    
}

class Mutable
{
    String name;
    Mutable(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Here My getMutables method is creating the objects and returning the cloned objects. But if so many threads or request access getMutables method then it will end up in creating multiple objects and soon out of memory error will come.

what to do in getMutables method so that, original Objects does not modified and more objects are not created.

Comment: This appears to be a homework question. You should read up on Collections in Java (I assume this is Java, even though you haven't said a word about it). Also, your Immutable class isn't immutable if it gets passed a List, since a List is an interface and many *mutable* kinds of lists may be passed to your "immutable" object.

Comment: First, create a defensive copy of the list *in the constructor*. Once your immutable class has its own copy that is guaranteed to never change, your `getMutables()` method may return [a wrapper that doesn’t allow the list to get modified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). Starting with Java 10, you can copy the original list into a [truly immutable list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) in the constructor, which you can hand out directly. *But that’s only the list.*

Comment: The `Mutable` instances stay mutable, even if you create a copy of the list, as the list only contains *references* to these instances and a copy of the list still contains references to the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of returning new ArrayList in getMutables(), we can return unmodifibleList of Mutable objects from getMutables(). 

public List<Mutable> getMutables()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.list);
    }

The unmodifiable Collection method of Collections class is used to return an unmodifiable view of the specified collection. This method allows modules to provide users with “read-only” access to internal collections.

Collections.unmodifiableList(mutableList);
Collections.unmodifiableSet(mutableSet);
Collections.unmodifiableMap(mutableMap);
```